# Using letsencrypt with Node Express application

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, https, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to make the switch to https with my application. I want to use Letsencrypt, but all tutorials I've seen online states that this requires a separate agent setup, to renew the certificate at constant intervals. I recently found greenlock-express which seems to bake the renewal process into the https wrapping of my express application, so I do not need to setup a separate server acting as an renewal agent (or have I misunderstood its purpose?).

This is what I have so far:

```
// Express
import * as http from 'http';
import * as https from 'https';
import * as e from 'express';
const LEX = require('greenlock-express');

/** Run this using MyServer.Initialize(process.argv) **/
export class MyServer {
  public app: e.Express;
  private clientPath = path.join(__dirname, './public');

  static Initialize(args: string[]): Promise<any> {
    return new MyServer()
      .start(args)
      .catch((error: any) => console.error(error);
  }

  constructor() { }

  start(args: string[]): Promise<https.Server> {
    // Simplified the code here, in order to only display relevant info
    return Promise.resolve(this.createServer());
  }

  public createServer(): https.Server {
    this.app = e(); // Creates an express application

    // Setup routes and standard stuff, which I removed to keep this question simple

    // Setup base route to everything else
    this.app.get('/*', (req: e.Request, res: e.Response) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(this.clientPath, 'index.html'));
    });
```

Now, if I return the following here, the app starts up fine and responds to http://localhost.

```
    return this.app.listen(80)
      .on('listening', () => console.log(`Serving on http://localhost/`));
```

But if I instead try to wrap the greenlock-express thingy around my app like this (this is from the example given at https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock-express, so I'm a bit disappointed that I could not get it to work out of the box):

```
    const lex = LEX.create({
      server: 'staging',
      email: 'my.email@mailprovider.com',
      agreeTos: true,
      configDir: 'cert/',
      approveDomains: ['mydomain.org']
    });

    // Force redirect to https
    http.createServer(lex.middleware(require('redirect-https')())).listen(80, function () {
      console.log('Listening for ACME http-01 challenges on', this.address());
    });

    return <https.Server> https.createServer(lex.httpsOptions, lex.middleware(this.app))
      .listen(443, () => console.log(`Serving on http://localhost/`));
  }
}
```

Nothing works. I do get redirected from http://localhost to https://localhost, but after that, the browser gives up and states that `The site cannot be reached`.

Why? Have I misunderstood something?

**EDIT**

I am aware that letsencrypt might have issues with resolving localhost as *my* domain. I do have a domain for my application, I just don't want to deploy something I'm not 100% sure works. I want the application to be runnable and testable from localhost. That's what I thought the

```
server: 'staging'
```

part of the greenlock-express config was for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I think you probably have. Letsencrypt provide free, short-term, verified SSL certificates for domains and subdomains (up to a limit of 10, I believe). What you are trying to do is get the LetsEncrypt servers to make a request to your application at http://localhost/.well-known/acme-challenge to verify you own the domain. Lets Encrypt will never resolve http://localhost to your server. You need to run this code and module on a server where it is reachable from the public internet on a domain that you own. Then LetsEncrypt will be able to reach your app, verify the domain, and issue a certificate. Then your site will run under SSL. That, or I have misuderstood something!

Comment: I have a domain, I just don't want to deploy code I cannot test locally. I will clarify that in the question. What you are saying is that the code above will work when deployed and run on `mydomain.org` but not from `localhost`? And my assumption that greenlock-express will take care of certification renewal AND wrap my application with https is correct? If so, how can I test my application on localhost?

Comment: Exactly that. LetsEncrypt wont (and cant) issue a certificate to a domain it cannot verify. By definition, that is localhost! You dont need to dev in https. Only production. IMHO you would be better off looking at hosting it behind NGINX and letting that take care of HTTPS encryption/decryption so that your app and the node server dont need to worry about it

Answer (score 2):

## No Localhost

You can't use localhost with Greenlock™, or any Let's Encrypt™ client.

You must access the site by the domain.

## Staging in Production

The `staging` option is for the public-facing, production environment. You can use a test domain such as `test.mysite.com` and `www.test.mysite.com` if you want to make sure it works before deploying on an existing site.

## New Version, Video Tutorial, Updated Docs

I'd suggest taking a look at the latest version and you'll probably find it much easier to get going:

https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js